# ¿Como no mostrar registros repetidos en un campo de una tabla en MYSQL Y PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada padecimientos, su estructura es la siguiente:

| id | padecimiento | hongos_recetados | Descripcion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COLERA | HONGO1, HONGO2, HONGO3 | DESCRIPCION1 |
| 2 | DOLOR DE HUESOS | HONGO4, HONGO2, HONGO1 | DESCRIPCION2 |
| 3 | EMBARAZADA | HONGO5, HONGO2, HONGO1 | DESCRIPCION3 |

Lo que quiero realizar es una consulta o función sea el caso donde si el usuario elige que tiene el padecimiento:

COLERA Y DOLOR DE HUESOS

Entonces el resultado me de lo siguiente en la pantalla:

PADECIMIENTOS:
COLERA y DOLOR DE HUESOS    .

HONGOS RECETADOS:
HONGO1, HONGO2, HONGO3, HONGO4

Lo que quiero es que si en dolor de huesos ya tiene el hongo1 y hongo2, entonces que se quite del resultado y ponga solo el hongo4 junto con el hongo1, hongo2,hongo3 del padecimiento colera.

Estoy utilizando php para realizar esto, tambien mysql. Espero me haya entendido. Saludos y gracias por adelantado, por el momento no llevo nada, no tengo idea de como savar los registros de hongos_recetados por si ya se recete alguno, que no lo vuelva a recetar

Comment: Si todavía estas a tiempo, te recomiendo [normalizar tu tabla](https://cnx.org/contents/qtZsLi-X@1/Un-ejemplo-simple-de-normalizaci%C3%B3n-de-bases-de-datos-relacionales-hasta-3FN). Un idea sería crear una tabla `hongos` donde guardas todos los hongos y cada uno tendrá su ID; una tabla `padecimiento_hongos` donde guardas la relación del padecimiento con los distingos hongos.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar tu código PHP?

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @Marcos, si no normalizas, esto se irá pronto de las manos y habrá hongos por todos lados sin ningún control. Y no digamos nada si tuvieras que hacer una consulta de estadísticas o de conteos o algo tan normal como querer saber qué hongos se relacionan con qué enfermedades, con qué enfermedades se relaciona el `hongo1`, con qué enfermedades NO se relaciona el `hongo99999`, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Comprendo ese tema, lo que pasa es que ya base de datos ya esta avanzada y ya no me es posible normalizarla.

Comment: Para obtener los hongos diferenciados, la única posibilidad con este diseño es traer todas las filas y luego pasar por procedimientos oscuros para limpiar los datos, como podrían ser: hacer un `explode` de tus valores separados por coma para encontrar los hongos que hay metidos en cada resultado y crear un array aparte metiendo, previa verificación, aquellos hongos que ya no estén en ese array. Como podrás entender, no tener los datos normalizados hace que cosas muy simples sean complicadas. Y eso sin hablar de los errores a que te expones. Imaginemos que un usuario despistado ...

Comment: ... escribió `ONGO1` en alguna parte, pero eso era `HONGO1`, esa simpleza puede crearte problemas muy muy serios, que le pueden costar la vida a personas por ejemplo. Imaginemos conteos o estadísticas, como te refería en otro comentario. No normalizar es peligroso, y complica todo a la larga. Y, normalizar siempre es posible, basta que te traces un plan y si la BD está en producción, puedes ir migrando tu tabla y cuando lo tengas todo, modificas el código allí donde haga falta. No te hagas ilusiones, si no normalizas, cualquier día tu sistema no se tendrá en pie, los hongos te comerán.