# ¿Como quitar objetos repetidos en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
 [
      0 => 'Array ( 
          [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_pa] => 6 
              [nombre_pade] => Alzheimer/ Demencia senil 
              [hongo] => CHAGA, MELENA DE LEÓN, CORDYCEPS 
              [descripcion] => Regenera neuronas, regenera la capa de mielina que envuelve a las fibras nerviosas, contiene NGF (factor de crecimiento nervioso), antioxidante, energético y vigorizante. ) 
              
          [1] => stdClass Object ( [id_pa] => 7 
              [nombre_pade] => Parkinson 
              [hongo] => CHAGA, MELENA DE LEÓN, CORDYCEPS 
              [descripcion] => Regenera neuronas, regenera la capa de mielina que envuelve a las fibras nerviosas, contiene NGF (factor de crecimiento nervioso), control del movimiento involuntario. ) )',
    ]
```

Lo que quiero realizar es la comparación del objeto [hongo], Como podrán notan el primero y el segundo objeto tiene:

```
  [hongo] => CHAGA, MELENA DE LEÓN, CORDYCEPS
```

Y lo que quiero es que me quite los objetos repetidos, es decir en este caso, dejar solamente un objeto de [hongo] => CHAGA, MELENA DE LEÓN, CORDYCEPS.

¿Se podría realizar?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tengas hasta el momento aunque no funcione completamente.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. ¿Qué debe ocurrir con los otros elementos que no se repiten, como son `id_pa`, `nombre_pade` y `descripcion`? Pon un ejemplo del objeto final esperado e incluye un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable del código que estás implementando.

Comment: Si lo que intentas resolver es el problema [planteado aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/536997/29967) quizá una mejor opción sería hacer un `GROUP_CONCAT()` sobre la columna de los hongos, luego hacer un `explode` y discriminar los hongos repetidos mediante un nuevo array. Es una idea, pero dado que no conozco el contexto, puede que me equivoque.

Comment: ¿Por que crear una nueva pregunta para buscar la misma respuesta?. Por favor, elimina esta pregunta, usa en botón [edit] en tu [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/536997/16597) y agregar esta info alla.